# How to move the cursor to the end of the currently active line within a textarea?

Tags: javascript, textarea

We have a `textarea` and want to set the cursor to the end of the **currently active line** where the cursor is situated.

Example content within the textarea:

```
This is our first line,
then comes a second line,
followed by a third line which holds *|* the cursor
and a fourth line.
```

Now the blinking cursor `*|*` should end up after the word `cursor` after execution of the javascript function.

What would be the javascript code to do this?

**Some initial Ideas:**

To get the line number this code can be used:

```
let line_number = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart).split("\n").length;
```

To go over all lines of the textarea:

```
let lines = textarea.value.split("\n");
```

Get length of current line:

```
let end_of_line = lines[line_number-1].length;
```

Then:

```
// set the cursor position to the end of the line
textarea.selectionStart = end_of_line;
```

Seems not to work...

Do we have to count all chars until the current line and then add the line length to it - this as the new cursor position?!

Comment: The question is unclear.  The browser already does all this automatically and also handles wrapped text where there is no ending carriage return.  Press the End key and the cursor (and position property) move to the end of the current line.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

```
// line where cursor is now
let line_number = textarea.value.substr(0, textarea.selectionStart).split("\n").length;

// split all lines of the textarea
let contentlines = textarea.value.split("\n");

let charcount = 0;

for (var i=0; i < line_number-1; i++)
{
    // count line break as one char
    charcount += contentlines[i].length + 1;
}

let end_of_line = contentlines[line_number-1].length;

textarea.selectionStart = charcount+end_of_line;
textarea.selectionEnd = charcount+end_of_line;
```

No guarantee that it is 100 % correct and works in all cases.